# How to get a hidden div to stay visible when hovered over with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I have a confusing issue. When my first div "leftbox" is hovered over, "rightbox" (the hidden div) displays, but it eventually disappears when "leftbox" is not hovered over. But I need "rightbox" to stay visible when rightbox is hovered over, then when the user's mouse leaves rightbox, *then* it should disappear. How can I get this to work? I'd really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a container class it works fine.

```js
$(function(){
 $('.container').hover(function(){
  var boxId = $(this).find("[data-id]").attr('data-id');
  $('#'+boxId).stop().fadeToggle();
 });
});
```

```css
.leftbox {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 float: left;
}
.rightbox {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 background: #99bf8f;
 margin-left: 110px;
 display: none;
}
.container {
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="leftbox" data-id="functionbox1"></div>
  <div class="rightbox" id="functionbox1"></div>
</div>

<script src="test.js"></script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No problem!  If you could mark as answer, it would help a lot.

Comment: I am, but I keep getting an error that I have to wait 5 minutes. Sorry, I'll wait until the timer is up